# In ES6 how to make base class function `null` in derived class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I derive class from `Animal` to `Dog`, I want to make `speak` function `null`,
before we can do it by prototype `Dog.prototype.speak = null` How to achive this in `es6`

```
class Animal { 
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  speak=null //as we do in Dog.prototype.speak = null
}
```

Comment: ES6 hasn't changed its means of inheritance. The `class` syntax is just sugar for setting up the same code that can be written in ES5. So after the declaration, you can still do `Dog.prototype.speak = null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in constructor:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.speak = null;
    }
}
```

Note that this does not set `Dog.prototype.speak` to null, but sets property on Dog`s instance.

```
let dog = new Dog();
Dog.prototype.speak === null; // false
dog.speak === null; // true
```

Comment: Any code using `Animal` and expecting it to have a `speak` method as advertised will call `animal.speak()` and hit a mysterious exception ("Unable to call null") because you've broken the super class' contract.

Comment: @ssube right, but this is what was asked for, right?

Comment: Literally, yes. But instead of showing people how to write more bad code, SO is supposed to show the right way to do it. Breaking a class' contract with inheritance is definitely bad, bad code.

Comment: @ssube: Sometimes there are just weird cases where someone needs to do something unorthodox. Not all of life fits into the most common patterns.

Comment: Yep, this was just an example, thought es6 dont have ability to do so.

Comment: @squint then the OP shouldn't be using inheritance. Most languages don't even allow this, at all, because you're no longer using inheritance.

Comment: @ssube: Fine. Whatever. You're missing the point. He's asking a specific question and hasn't given a reason except to say that he wants to know if it can be done. You can either try to solve all the world's bad code here in this one question, or you can trust that this user has some particular use for this knowledge, and give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Removing a method from a subclass (or single instance of the subclass) is a particularly dangerous anti-pattern. Without the `speak` method, `Dog` no longer extends `Animal` but the prototype chain claims it will. That is misleading to any users of `Animal`, who may try to call `animal.speak()` and suddenly find themselves with an `Uncaught TypeError: animal.speak is not a function`.

Redefine the function as a no-op:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  speak() {
    // noop: dogs can't speak
  }
}
```

Or, if the superclass allows it, make it throw:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  speak() {
    throw new Error("Dogs can't speak.");
  }
}
```

Actually making the function null is an anti-pattern, since every consumer of the `Animal` interface will need to know that some methods might not exist, which breaks the concept of inheritance (children can add but not take away).

Having a subclass throw on a bad operation is somewhat common practice, but turning the function into a noop (silently skip) is valid as well. In JS, given how the JIT compiler works, the noop function should be elided and not actually called, so there should be no performance impact (or very, very little).

Comment: Agree, but in my project previous code is like that, I'm trying to convert to `es6`, by using `es6` have we removed this feasibility?

Comment: @user2285490 being able to subvert inheritance was an antipattern that slipped in because of prototype mutability. It's rather dangerous to do, since *every single* piece of code that uses an `Animal` suddenly has to change `animal.speak()` to `animal.speak ? animal.speak() || other`.

Comment: By removing a method from the constructor (or prototype), you've now created a whole new class (`Dog`) that **does not extend** `Animal` anymore. You'd be better off creating `SilentAnimal` without the `speak` method at all, or removing `speak` from `Animal` and creating `Speaker extends Animal { speak() ... }`.